# changing activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I developed an app with android studio, containing a MainActivity, a SettingsActivity and additional Activities. When the app returns from SettingsActivity the MainActivity will continue from 'OnResume'. When the app returns from the additional Activities the MainActivity will go through 'OnCreate' + 'OnResume'.

I would like to change this behavior, so if the app returns from additional Activities it should only walk through 'OnResume' (avoiding 'OnCreate').

How to do this?

EDIT:

THANKS A LOT. You really helped me with your hints. I had forgotten to implement the handling for 'id == android.R.id.home' in the additional Activities, the return to MainActivity (in SettingsActivity I did). After adding this part the app works correctly and as desired.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: It will only do oncreate again if you explicitly finish the main activity or otherwise remove it from the stack

Comment: can you post ur code of starting new activity?

Comment: Are you coming back to main activity from additional activity ? If you came back finishing the additional activity, it goes in OnResume() only ....

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity has been killed when you go to AdditionalActivities. You must not kill your mainActivity. You must not call finish() code when starting the next activity.

Please update show your code on how do you startActivity from one activity to another.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is not to use Activity you can go with fragments where you can play with each fragment and share data with shared preference 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html